# Why does p|4q also mean p|q if p is odd?

Tags: divisibility

Why does p|4q also mean p|q if p is odd?

It might be a simple question but it's in the answers and I want to know.

Answer (score 5):

Because $p$ and $4$ would be relatively prime. This is a general statement. If $p|ab$ and $(p,a)=1$, then $p|b$.

Answer (score 2):

For this, we should cite [Euclid's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma): if $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|ab$, or both. If $p$ is odd, then $p$ does not divide $4$. So $p$ must divide $b$.